# how to have table rows and columns boards and not having intersections

Tags: html, css

I want to design my table in a way that intersections are not crossed, here is my table css:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table td, table th {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
table tr:first-child th {
    border-top: 0;
}
table tr:last-child td {
    border-bottom: 0;

}
table tr td:first-child,
table tr th:first-child {
    border-left: 0;    border-right: 0;
}
table tr td:last-child,
table tr th:last-child {
    border-right: 0;
    border-left: 0;
        }
.product_column {
padding: 3px;
margin-right: 5px;
margin-left: 5px;
}
```

[image]

I want to have the borders and not having borders in the intersections like this below image:

[image]

this will put the products in the table in each **if** condition:

```
<?php if($colunmNumber =0)
    echo('<tr><td>');
    else 
    echo('<td style="text-align:center;">');
    $colunmNumber = $counter % $columns;  
?>
<div class="product_column" >

    <div class="product_image"><?php if (  (function_exists('has_post_thumbnail')) && (has_post_thumbnail())  ) { ?>
        //some php code
    </div>
    <div class="product_title"   >
    //some php code
    </div>
</div>
```

and if it is possible with tables I do not know it. it seems that I should add div element in the intersections but I could not know how. or maybe just drawing lines or using span ? but I do not know how to solve it when I have this loop function fetching the products

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would add 2 rows in between each relevant row and two columns between each relevant column and then you can create this exactly. But it requires a lot more cells to code, but using css and classes, that should be easy!

Comment: @DenverWilliam I tried my best! it seems possible but again I could not

Answer (score 1):

I did this in a table form, but you can easily translate it into div elements using the same philosophy.

It is too much to code here, so I made you the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/5WzVV/

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td class="r"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td><td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td><td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="c"></td>
    <td class="e">A</td>
    <td class="c br"></td><td class="c"></td>
    <td class="e">B</td>
    <td class="c br"></td><td class="c"></td>
    <td class="e">C</td>
    <td class="c"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="r"></td>
    <td class="bb"></td>
    <td></td><td></td>
    <td class="bb"></td>
    <td></td><td></td>
    <td class="bb"></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="r"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td><td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td><td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td class="e">D</td>
    <td class="br"></td><td></td>
    <td class="e">E</td>
    <td class="br"></td><td></td>
    <td class="e">F</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="r"></td>
    <td class="bb"></td>
    <td></td><td></td>
    <td class="bb"></td>
    <td></td><td></td>
    <td class="bb"></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="r"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td><td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td><td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td class="e">G</td>
    <td class="br"></td><td></td>
    <td class="e">H</td>
    <td class="br"></td><td></td>
    <td class="e">I</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="r"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td><td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td><td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and the css:

```
td.e { // cell with an product
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
td.r { // spacer cell row
    height: 5px;
}
td.c { // spacer cell column
    width: 5px;
}
td.bb { // border at bottom of first spacer row
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
td.br { // border at bottom of first spacer column
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use table form and give style to your rows.
here is my sample html code :

```
<html>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="samplePic.jpg"</td>
        <td>
            <div
                style="float: left; background: url(vline.jpg ) repeat-y top; width: 20px; height: 200px"></div>
        <td>
        <td><img src="samplePic.jpg"</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div
                style="float: left; width: 167px; padding: 15px 0 15px 0; background: url(hline.jpg) repeat-x center;"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div style="float: left; width: 20px;"></div>
        <td>
        <td>
            <div
                style="float: left; width: 167px; padding: 15px 0 15px 0; background: url(hline.jpg) repeat-x center;"></div>
        </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><img src="samplePic.jpg"</td>
        <td>
            <div
                style="float: left; background: url(vline.jpg ) repeat-y top; width: 20px; height: 200px"></div>
        <td><td><img src="samplePic.jpg"</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, votting up